# Mods should be stopped from closing reopened stuff automatically the second time.

Tags: discussion, rant

That's quite an outrage, why go so far against the grain to inflict your will upon the masses and not even acknowledge why you are doing so?

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11033/which-programming-jargon-words-are-your-least-favorite-closed

Give me a break, why wasn't

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2119/which-programming-jargon-words-are-your-favorite

closed as well?

Comment: [The Programming Jargon Words question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2119/which-programming-jargon-words-are-your-favorite) is now closed and deleted.

Answer (score 7):

The question (11033) was closed by five non-moderators, reopened by five other non-moderators and then finally closed by two non-moderators and a moderator.

So far 8 non-moderators have voted to close the question. The moderator has only intervened at a late stage. Personally I would have waited until there were 3 or even 4 non-moderator close votes, and I would potentially vote to close even if I personally disagreed with decision.

In this case I'm not sure that either question passes the new constructive subjective test.

Comment: Yeah, well nobody has given a decent reason why one should be left open and the other should be closed.

Comment: @Peter - I agree with you, but I'm not going to arbitrarily close 2119.

Comment: then this is a load of hooey eh? http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/176/lots-of-subjective-questions-here/177#177

Comment: @Peter - that was before the new constructive subjective policy was introduced - and if the community wants a question closed I'll only help it along, I won't act contrary to their wishes.